# How can I find and replace using regex for multi-line code?

Tags: c#, regex

I my.NET project that uses the MOQ .NET mocking library. Recently, I planned to migrate it from MOQ to NSubstitute. As there is a substantial change in my codebase, I decided to use regex find and replace for it. My issue is, I have following code snippet.

```
this.objectStorageMock.Setup(broker =>
    broker.InsertCalendarAsync(someCalendar))
        .ThrowsAsync(npgsqlException);
        
this.objectStorageMock.Setup(broker =>
    broker.DeleteBlobAsync(someFilePath))
        .ThrowsAsync(httpResponseCriticalException);
```

and I need to change it into this,

```
this.objectStorageMock.DeleteBlobAsync(someFilePath).ThrowsAsync(httpResponseCriticalException);        


this.objectStorageMock.InsertCalendarAsync(someCalendar).ThrowsAsync(npgsqlException);
```

So I used following regex for it,

**Regex Pattern:**

```
this\.([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*)\.Setup\(broker => broker\.(\w+)\(([^)]*)\)\)\.ThrowsAsync\(([^)]*)\);
```

**Replacement String:**

```
this.$1.$2($3).ThrowsAsync($4);
```

This works fine when the original code is in a single line, but it exists as multiple lines below (Because each developer has formatted the code in different ways).

```
this.objectStorageMock.Setup(broker =>
    broker.InsertCalendarAsync(someCalendar))
        .ThrowsAsync(npgsqlException);

this.objectStorageMock.Setup(broker =>
    broker.DeleteBlobAsync(someFilePath)).ThrowsAsync(httpResponseCriticalException);
```

How should I handle this?

Comment: Which editor? or script?

Comment: @shingo Visual studio 2022

Comment: You could try `\s` to match whitespaces characters.

Comment: Simplest solution would probably be to replace `\n[\r\t ]+` with a single space, prior to running the regex replacement you're currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex, I inserted `[\s\r]*` between all the tokens, which can match any whitespace character (including line breaks) in Visual Studio.

```
this[\s\r]*\.[\s\r]*([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*)[\s\r]*\.[\s\r]*Setup[\s\r]*\([\s\r]*broker[\s\r]*=>[\s\r]*broker[\s\r]*\.[\s\r]*(\w+)[\s\r]*\([\s\r]*([^)]*)[\s\r]*\)[\s\r]*\)[\s\r]*\.[\s\r]*ThrowsAsync[\s\r]*\([\s\r]*([^)]*)[\s\r]*\)[\s\r]*;
```

Comment: Thank in advance :)

Comment: `\r` is already contained in `\s` which is a [short for `[ \t\r\n\f]`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) in most major regex flavors.

Comment: @bobblebubble The document does say so, but in actual testing, `\s` cannot match `\r` in the search.

Comment: @shingo I missed it's VB.net related (thought C#), yes there are some differences.